# synchronisation of localhost mysql database with online server databse

Tags: mysql, database

I want to conduct online test in different schools.The web application for online test portal is made in php and mysql. For this i am conducting test on local servers in different school.Suppose i conduct test in school A on a particular day and exported the sql file to live server. On next day again i conduct a test and now i want to update the database which was exported to online server with these new data(news rows). How can i connect my localhost mysql database with server's mysql database. I don't want that data should be overwritten and i lost my previously exported data to online server. I just need to update any new data if any such is there. That means if there is any new row in previously created table then it must update the online database table with new row and if a new table is created then it must be created in online server also. Please help me how to achieve this ?

Comment: This question apart from having an obvious answer is off topic for SO

Comment: Why not use a single MySQL database? Not sure if that is what you are doing. Additionally you can always run scripts/MySQL dump to copy the production database over to your local database. I don't know what you mean by "sync" here.

Comment: `Suppose i conduct test in school A on a particular day and exported the sql file to live server.` why do you need to do this ?

Comment: See i just want to just transfer data from local database to online database .

Comment: Why not write the data directly to an "online" database server ?

Comment: i need to conduct test on local servers because internet based test is not possible for 60 students due to low internet speed but i also want to update my online database to maintain the record

Comment: I am not sure if that is a good practice at all. In either case you might need to look into something like MySQL dump/backup using MySQL Workbench. you can also look into an ETL based solution like Pentaho Data Integration (PDI).

Comment: so what is a good practice in ur opinion